# Apply function on a set, which is a data frame with a column of rsplit objects

Tags: r, purrr

I want to apply a function on a set generated by the bootstraps function.

The data looks like this

````
# Create 4 variables
Position <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Sample <- c(4,19,14,33,37,11,28,38)
Dist <- c(0.1,1.0,0.3,4.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,3.0)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(Position,Sample,Dist)```
````

And then the bootstrap set is generated by

```
TAVTest_BOOT <- bootstraps(df,times = 10, apparent = TRUE)
```

This generates a set with two columns: one is made of lists of bootstrapped data, and the second has the ID of each bootstrapped list row.

What I have tried to do is to apply a simple formula to be calculated and added to a new, third column in the set. The formula is quite simple,

(number of Sample * number of Position-1)/(sum Dist)

I would like to add this calculation per row in another column in the set iterating each list with the formula to add the data in a new column created through mutate, etc., but I haven't been able to figure out how to reference this through map or another function in the Purrr library...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rsample::analysis()` to convert a `rsplit` object to a `data.frame`.

With this we can build a function `my_fun` which will calculate the values of the new column.

Below is my attempt. I'm not sure what your desired output is. Below I'm wrapping the result in `list()` because the formula returns more than one element per row. If our function returns exactly one element per row we don't need to wrap it in `list()`.

```r
library(rsample)
library(dplyr)

my_fun <- function(dat) {
  dat <- analysis(dat)
  
  (dat$Sample * dat$Position - 1) / sum(dat$Dist) 
}

TAVTest_BOOT %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new = list(my_fun(splits)))

#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    splits        id          new      
#>    <list>        <chr>       <list>   
#>  1 <split [8/1]> Bootstrap01 <dbl [8]>
#>  2 <split [8/2]> Bootstrap02 <dbl [8]>
#>  3 <split [8/2]> Bootstrap03 <dbl [8]>
#>  4 <split [8/3]> Bootstrap04 <dbl [8]>
#>  5 <split [8/2]> Bootstrap05 <dbl [8]>
#>  6 <split [8/1]> Bootstrap06 <dbl [8]>
#>  7 <split [8/2]> Bootstrap07 <dbl [8]>
#>  8 <split [8/3]> Bootstrap08 <dbl [8]>
#>  9 <split [8/3]> Bootstrap09 <dbl [8]>
#> 10 <split [8/3]> Bootstrap10 <dbl [8]>
#> 11 <split [8/8]> Apparent    <dbl [8]>
```

Data from OP

```r
Position <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Sample <- c(4,19,14,33,37,11,28,38)
Dist <- c(0.1,1.0,0.3,4.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,3.0)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(Position,Sample,Dist)

TAVTest_BOOT <- bootstraps(df,times = 10, apparent = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I was hoping to get a single result value for each row instead of another list. What should be done to accomplish that?

Comment: @EstefaniaVillanueva: It depends on the exact calculation, I'm not sure if my interpretation of your wording "(number of Sample * number of Position-1)/(sum Dist)" is correct. I calculate for each data.frame `dat`: `(dat$Sample * dat$Position - 1) / sum(dat$Dist)`, but this yields a vector since `dat$Sample` is a vector with more than one value, so is the product of `dat$Sample * dat$Position - 1`. Maybe you have a different calculation in mind?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to comment, I was on the field. I see what the problem is. The thing is that instead of dat$Sample and dat$position what is needed is actually the command n_distinct to get the number of unique Sample and the number of unique Position. those are real numbers and not two vectors.

Comment: I changed the function code to reflect that and it worked. Here is how it looks now.

`my_fun<- function(dat) {
  dat <- analysis(dat)
  
  ((n_distinct(dat$Sample) * n_distinct(dat$Position) - 1)) / sum(dat$Dist) 
}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stumped on this for the longest time. The insight provided by your comment got me unstuck.